# Background Images in Mobile

Tags: css, performance, responsive-design

It is a simple question.

If I remove the gradient and the background image (css) in mobile devices, you will gain more performance?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .header { background: #333;}
}

.header { 
   background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(35,37,38, .9), rgba(65,67,69, .9)),
    url(img/bg-min.jpg);
}
```

Comment: But for real, if you completely remove both, you will for sure gain at least some performance. But whether that really makes a difference would have to be measured in your case.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question shortly: it will improve your performances and for your users. You have to load in less, so it will automatically increase your performance level. I think in your case removing the gradient will have the most effect. Simple background colors don't really matter all too much.

I'm not sure if it will be heavy noticeable, but yes, every decrease of code is "increased" performance!